# alchemy API doesnt accept my local file

Tags: rest, uri, alchemyapi

Here is my request:

```
> curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:
> application/json" -X GET
> http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/image/ImageGetRankedImageKeywords?apikey=<key>&image=file%3A%2F%2Ftmp%2Fimage.jpg&imagePostMode=not-raw&outputMode=json
```

Following http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/image-tagging/image.html

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 04:27:56 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 440
>   Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: no-cache
>   X-AlchemyAPI-CurrentVersion: 12.15 X-AlchemyAPI-Error-Msg:
>   content-is-empty X-AlchemyAPI-Key:  X-AlchemyAPI-Params:
>   sentiment=0&knowledgeGraph=0&detectedLanguage=unknown&submitLanguage=detect
>   X-AlchemyAPI-Status: ERROR X-AlchemyAPI-Total-Transactions: 4
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> ERROR
>       content-is-empty
>       By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of
>   Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html
>       
>       4

Why?
The image exists:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/trash1.jpg 
-rw-r-----@ 1 xx  staff  47846 May 12 15:49 /tmp/image.jpg
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Their support helped me.
Essentially i need to POST the image directly.
Can't use the "image" parameter and filling it with the name of the local file. That parameter actually needs to contain the contents of the image file instead. So instead need to use imagePostMode=raw, and just add the file as the post body, which I would recommend. Something like this:

```
wget -qO- --post-file YOUR_IMAGE.png "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/image/ImageGetRankedImageKeywords?apikey=API_KEY&imagePostMode=raw"
```